# How to change the background color of a non-visible item in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, background, navigation-drawer

I’m trying to make a navigation drawer that changes the background color of items in a ListView based on integers received from another part of the application – i.e. not based on what item is clicked. I have managed to color two separate items in the navigation drawer, but apparently my way only works for items that are visible. I tried doing a work-around that involved scrolling to the desired item before changing the background color, but I couldn’t figure out a way to calculate what number the item had after the scroll-down, since getChildAt(position) seems to start at the first visible item.

Is there any way I can solve this without having to re-do the entire navigation drawer? I searched for a few guides on how to do a sidebar menu like this, but most meant I had to set up static items in an XML – and since my list needs to change regularly I figured this would be the easiest way, but for all I know it might as well be a bad way to go about it.

This is the code that is running at onCreate:

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // My work-around to not get force close if item isn't visible
        if (itemOne > -1) {
            int visibleChildCount = (dList.getLastVisiblePosition() - dList
                    .getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
            if (visibleChildCount > itemOne)
                dList.getChildAt(itemOne).setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#d3d3d3"));
        }
        if (itemTwo > -1) {
            int visibleChildCount = (dList.getLastVisiblePosition() - dList
                    .getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
            if (visibleChildCount > itemTwo)
                dList.getChildAt(itemTwo).setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#33B5E5"));
        }

    }
};


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And the rest of the code:

```
dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayOfItems);
dList.setAdapter(adapter);

dList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        dList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        dLayout.closeDrawers();
        stateChanged = true;

            // Non-relevant action when item is clicked

    }
});
```

Finally, the activity XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

     <!-- Items in my main activity -->

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#fff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Just let me know if you need any additional information. I’m sorry if I’ve missed the answer in anyone of the other questions or if this is a stupid question. I’ve tried searching for this a while now, but since I’m a beginner I haven’t quite managed to figure out how to do this, so if anyone could help me with this I’d really appreciate it!

**Edit**:

Thanks to darnmason I finally got it to work. If anyone is interested, the code above will work with the following changes.

Change the line *adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayOfItems);* to this:

```
adapter = new NavigationAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayOfItems);
```

Then create the class NavigationAdapter.java with the following content (and make sure the integers itemOne/itemTwo are reachable from the main activity in some way):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    // Create constructor matching super
    public NavigationAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    // Override method so that you can modify the view
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // modify your view depending on position
        if (position == itemOne) {
                boolean positionOne = true;
            view.setBackgroundColor(positionOne ? Color.parseColor("#d3d3d3") : Color.WHITE);
        } else if (position == itemTwo) {
                boolean positionTwo = true;
            view.setBackgroundColor(positionTwo ? Color.parseColor("#33B5E5") : Color.WHITE);
        } else
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you **delete** the following lines from my previous code:

```
        // My work-around to not get force close if item isn't visible
        if (itemOne > -1) {
            int visibleChildCount = (dList.getLastVisiblePosition() - dList
                    .getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
            if (visibleChildCount > itemOne)
                dList.getChildAt(itemOne).setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#d3d3d3"));
        }
        if (itemTwo > -1) {
            int visibleChildCount = (dList.getLastVisiblePosition() - dList
                    .getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
            if (visibleChildCount > itemTwo)
                dList.getChildAt(itemTwo).setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#33B5E5"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendering of each item in the list should be handled in the adapter. What you should really do is extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView` to be something like this:

```
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
boolean selected = position matches any of your indexes;
view.setBackgroundColor(selected ? selectedColor : normalColor);
return view;
```

Another way to set the background is to use a state list drawable with selected state and default state. Then you just need to call `view.setSelected(selected)`

Edit: Extending ArrayAdapter

Create a new file, I like to create a new package to group all custom adapters under something like `com.domain.name.adapters` for example.

```
// Create new class extending ArrayAdapter<String>
public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    // Create constructor matching super
    public NavigationAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    // Override method so that you can modify the view
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // modify your view depending on position
        return view;
    }
}
```

Then just substitute `NavigationAdapter` for `ArrayAdapter` in your code. You may have to expose methods to set the selected indexes on the `NavigationAdapter` unless you have them in some glabally accessible location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If it wouldn't be too much trouble, I'd appreciate if you could explain it a bit further though. I'm still new to all of this, so I'm not sure how I extend the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Added some more info there

Comment: Perfect! That was just what I've been looking for. If I could I'd vote up too.